# nohup php script mysql issues in the middle

Tags: php, mysql, nohup

I have a php script that I run via nohup that had this issue in the middle of it with mysql. My script goes though a couple hundred databases and performs schema migrations via. (all same schema)

```
`system("mysql --host=$db_host --user=$db_user --password=$db_password -v -v -v $database < ../update.sql");`
```

In the middle of the migrations this happens:

```
--------------
ALTER TABLE `phppos_customers` ADD `current_sales_for_discount` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `current_spend_for_points`
--------------

Terminal close -- sending "KILL QUERY 966" to server ...
Terminal close -- query aborted
Aborted
```

The php script continues to run and the other databases do NOT have this issue. What would cause this?

php script runs via:

`nohup php update_pos_databases.php > results.txt 2>&1 </dev/null &`

This is on Mac OS X 10.11.3

Here are my timeout values:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%_timeout";
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout      | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout            | 30       |
| net_write_timeout           | 60       |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout           | 60       |
| wait_timeout                | 28800    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which ones should I change?

Here is more information on the code:

```
foreach($databases as $database)
{
    echo "Running queries on $database\n***********************************\n";
    system("mysql --host=$db_host --user=$db_user --password=$db_password -v -v -v $database < ../update.sql"); 
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you get a timeout by mysql. Do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%_timeout"` (please edit/add result to your answer) to get a list of relevant variables from the server. Inspect `connect_timeout`, `wait_timeout`,  `interactive_timeout`, probably one of them is too low.

Comment: I have added the information to the question. Are these values in seconds or milliseconds? Which one should I change? What are good values?

Comment: Do you think it is innodb_lock_wait_timeout?

Comment: Timeouts are specified in seconds. AFAIK your values should be sufficient. How long does your script run before it terminates?

Comment: The script doesn't terminate it just has a blip on the middle on that one database. After that error it continues to run. I have updated my question with more code.

Comment: It should also be noted if I run this script by itself on one database that was having the issue without doing all 300; it works fine without issue and does the whole migrating in about 20 seconds

Comment: I had an interesting issue. I started the command; then closed the terminal and it failed like before. So it must be something related to that and NOT mysql. I thought `nohup` was suppose to avoid this. Note the terminal application is mac os x and the databases are local

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions (found on an old reddit thread):

Use "disown" after running the nohup command.  e.g.

```
nohup php update_pos_databases.php > results.txt 2>&1 </dev/null &
disown %1
```

or:

Use "screen" instead of nohup.

Comment: I was reading this http://askubuntu.com/a/612106 It is almost like the system command is being spawn in the same shell which is why the php script keeps running but the system command is somehow tied to terminal.

Comment: BTW your command does work; but I am puzzled to why I even need disown %1.

Comment: The disown command removes the job from the jobs table - basically this means that the system won't send the SIGHUP signal to it if the terminal closes.  This may or may not have the effect you require.  Perhaps you actually need to disown each mysql command as they're run.